# SQL Statement: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to check if a user has an order which links with order_items table and that order_items table has the product while ensuring same user ID and order ID. How would I go about doing this?

I have attempted to do this:

```
 $verify_order = Order::where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->join('order_items', 'orders.id', 'order_items.order_id')
                ->where('order.items.product_id', $product_id)->get();
```

but I get an error message of:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

[Orders Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHWDY.png)

[Order_items table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ0TQ.png)

[Products Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfSzv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders and orders_item have both redundant user_id as column.

Best would be to remove the column from orderrs_item

or add the table name to the user_id

```
 $verify_order = Order::where('orders.user_id', $user_id)
                ->join('order_items', 'orders.id', 'order_items.order_id')
                ->where('order.items.product_id', $product_id)->get();
```